# How to add paragraph in rest api including whitespaces?

Tags: reactjs, api, rest

I am fetching string from api and it looks like this[string original format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqtIx.png) in console.log()
but, when I use p tag to print it on website it become like this [this is how it print on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6tKr.png)

how do I maintain the original format of string and print on website

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want whitespace within your database? This doesn't seem logical to me, and in MYSQL depending the version # whitespace is automatically truncated. If you are trying to create easier readability, creating a function when you are getting the data from the database instead

Comment: You are wrong @IamToobDude. MySQL never tempers with data. @ Abhi attach code snippet where data is being saved to DB, also attach snippet of code of component with text area.

Comment: You will need to look into both contents structurally. Right-click on the text, click on inspect for the first one and copy the actual structure into a text editor. Then do it for the second one as well and compare the two. What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your string to use HTML tags. For instance you use `\&nbsp;` for white space. However if you want to convert your regular String to preserve its formatting in HTML, I wrote a method `public static java.lang.String formatStringToPreserveIndentationForHtml(java.lang.String rawText)` that converts your regular String into HTML formatted string that preserve the original format. Here is a [javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html#formatStringToPreserveIndentationForHtml-java.lang.String-) for that method. The class `TextUtils` that has this method is part of Open source MgntUtils java library written and maintained by me. You can get it as `maven artifact` and on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including javadoc and source code)

Comment: thanks this actually works but, when i print it on website it shrunk , the question is updated check it again please

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a prefix and a postfix before and after your content before it is being posted to the server, so a string like

```
"   sdfjsgfhks    sdgsdjfsj    
    sdjksjh     sdkhsfs      "
```

would be converted to something like

```
"!^!   sdfjsgfhks    sdgsdjfsj    
    sdjksjh     sdkhsfs      !^!"
```

before it is posted. Then, the API side, fully aware of the wrapping would trim the prefix and postfix from the string it received.

Comment: thanks  actually database is not changing the string format but, when i print it on website it shrunk , the question is updated check it again please